# In elasticsearch, do we need to put suggest in doc?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I added the suggest to doc index as the official docs said:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/music/song/1?refresh=true' -d '{
    "name" : "Nevermind",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
        "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
        "payload" : { "artistId" : 2321 },
        "weight" : 34
    }
}'
```

but if I have serval properties to suggest, for example name,company,industry to suggest.

Do I need to put the suggest part in the origin doc, or just start a new index for suggester? What's the advantage and disadvantage? Thanks.